# Multi threading in solr

Tags: solr

When I run solr 5 and above, it runs within its own Jetty container, it no longer runs under tomcat. When I retrieve the process id and run a top on that given process id , "top -p pid", I do see the one thread running.

But to know how many threads are being spawned by this one thread, if I use **ps huH -p pid**, I do see multiple threads showing up , linked to this parent pid. Are these the multiple threads spawned by solr?

Are these threads serving queries/compacting index....etc ? If that is the case, these thread count should go down , if the machine is idle.

Can somebody throw some light on the solr threads or point me to the right document?

Thanks
SR0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see exactly what each thread is doing by going to the "Thread dump" pane available under Solr's Admin page:

[image: The location of the Thread dump menu item in the Solr Dashboard, right beneath Java Properties (the sixth item)]

If you open this page you'll get a list of all the threads running inside Solr's JVM, and you can expand each one to see a stack trace for what task it is performing:

[image: List of threads active in an idle Solr installation]

As you can see from the names of these threads (.. not just those three in my screenshot), they're performing a variety of tasks - those prefixed with `qtp` is Jetty threads, while those prefixed with `zk` are responsible for Zookeeper operations. Other keep track of scheduled tasks and triggers, some execute searches, some might be running an optimize or commit, some may be indexing documents (handling Tika for example), etc.

Most of these threads are kept around since they implement central functionality that has to be running all the time, such as watching for changes from Zookeeper, making searches against the index, keeping track of scheduled tasks, etc. Keeping them around is not very expensive either.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh for the input, Yes I was using this thread-dump interface to check the threads and to look at the trace, thought I can co-relate each with a process on the server by using the "ps" and look at the resource usage of that. But this info is helpful. Thanks